# macOS using html tags in nstextfield

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield, nstextview, richtext

Im wondering is there any ways to make this possible:

I have a nstextfield(or nstextview). And I also have one button, clicking on that should activate Bold mode for selected text, or the text that would written further.

First idea I had - is to use attributes for characters that would be written further, but this idea is not so good, as I would need to save that string in file later. I can save attributed string, but this gives me not proper format, what I would like to see is kind of  or smth like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your "First idea" is correct. Within your program you use `NSAttributedString` to add bold etc. your text. When you wish to save the text you can convert to HTML, or a number of other formats, and reading these formats and converting back to `NSAttributed` is also supported. A good place to start is [Formatted Documents and Attributed Strings](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Articles/HTMLFilesandAttributedStrings.html).